# How to insert two blank lines between title and header in list-table of reStrutureText?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

Here is the snippet of  list-table in reStrutureText.

```
.. list-table:: Frozen Delights!
  :widths: 15 10 30
  :header-rows: 1

  * - Treat
    - Quantity
    - Description
  * - Albatross
    - 2.99
    - On a stick!
  * - Crunchy Frog
    - 1.49
    - If we took the bones out, it wouldn't be
      crunchy, now would it?
  * - Gannet Ripple
    - 1.99
    - On a stick!
```

The display effect.

[image]

How to insert two blank lines  between  title `Frozen Delights!` and header line `Treat   Quantity  Description`  ?

To test `\n` in online tool http://rst.ninjs.org/, `\n` doesn't work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I never made tables using Python but does `\n` do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is a style modification with visual space, and not actual line breaks, then modify the style sheet of the rendered HTML.

```
caption {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

[image: caption style]